# Whether determinant will be zero?

Tags: matrices, determinant

I know that if rank of a matrix is less than n in nxn matrix then it's determinant will be zero.

If determinant is zero, does it always imply that rank is less than n or rows are linearly dependent ?

Comment: Yes, and both of those conditions are in turn equivalent to the matrix not being invertible. There are lots and lots of such conditions, maybe 10+, which you should be able to find in any good linear algebra textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [invertible matrix theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#The_invertible_matrix_theorem) gives a long list of equivalent conditions for $n\times n$ matrices.

Some of the most often used in an elementary course would be:

The following are equivalent statements for a square $n\times n$ matrix $A$:

- $A$ is invertible
- $A$ row reduces to the identity matrix
- The kernel of $A$ is trivial
- The rank of $A$ is equal to $n$
- The rows of $A$ are independent
- The columns of $A$ are independent
- The determinant of $A$ is nonzero
- $\dots$

All of the above will simultaneously be true or simultaneously be untrue, so in your specific question, yes $rank(A)<n\iff \det(A)=0\iff$ rows of $A$ are linearly dependent.

Oftentimes it is an extended problem given in homework to prove part or all of the list of equivalent conditions are in fact equivalent.